# How to fix WinForms MonthCalendar selectionstart and selectionend

Tags: winforms, monthcalendar

I am using a month calendar for user to enter data range. But when user scrolls through months, the selected range is changed automatically.

Why is that happening and how can I make that selectionstart and selectionend properties are changed only when I manually select range in MonthCalendar?

In Msdn (and elsewhere) I had no luck to find information about this behavior, anyone has a clue?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you mean that the user can only view x months in advance, or do you mean the user should only see y months at any one time? If it's the former, what about:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxdate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jbutler483 no, I don't intend to restrict user to view specific months, the problem is that those selectedstart and selectedend dates are changing whenever I scroll through MonthCalendar months

Comment: Can't really guess at the problem, be sure to distinguish between the DateChanged and DateSelected events.  Sounds like you want the latter.